# Lightning Experience Specialist - Step 6 - Unable to complete

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am stuck in this challenge and not sure why is it not completing. Please have a look at below details.

Error Message -

`Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: The Fulfillment Cancellation Automation process does not appear to be working properly. Make sure that a cancelled Fulfillment updates the Adventure Package correctly.`
My Process builder is as follows:

```
Object: Fulfillment

Entry Criteria: [Fulfillment__c].Status__c = Cancelled AND [Fulfillment__c].Schedule_Date__c > TODAY()

Immediate Actions: 
Based on [Fulfillment__c].Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems


Field Update Filter condition : 
Line Item ID  equals Formula [FullFillment__c].AdventurePackageId__c

Field to Update :
Sales Price equal to [Fulfillment__c].Deposit__c
```

I did some finding on web and have changed the below things as well but not working for me.

The Explorer__c field was set to "Required" and "What to do if the lookup record is deleted?" was set to "Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship.".

**I updated the "Required" to false and changed "What to do if the lookup record is deleted?" to "Clear the value of this field. You can't choose this option if you make this field required."
I have unrequired the Explorer__c field on the layout too.**

After all the above changes, I am still not able to complete the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this as well, and I think there may well be a bug in their test.

I've manually tested the processes, and it works as described. The Sales Price on the Adventure Package gets updated to the Fulfillment's Deposit amount.

Looking in the debug logs, the query clearly selects 1 record (which is what we'd expect) into a List called `fullfillmentList` before the code immediately fails an assertion with the message `Fulfillment list is empty`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this error is showing because, you might have deactivated the previous process flow i.e Fulfillment Creation, which also should be active for completion of this step in the superbadge